# Continuity of function defined implicitly in Hilbert space

Tags: functional-analysis, continuity, implicit-function

Let $H$ be a Hilbert space. Suppose I have a function $f\colon [0,1] \to H$ defined as the unique solution of
$$f(x) = F(x, f(x))$$
where $F\colon \mathbb{R} \times H \to H$ is some given function which is continuous in the first argument and may be differentiable in some sense in the second argument.

I want to be able to say that $f$ is continuous, given some assumptions of $F$. What kind of theorems can I use for this?

Comment: What if $F(x, y)=y$? Then any $f$ solves your equation (including discontinuous ones).

Comment: Well, you could try to use the implicit function theorem.

Comment: @PhoemueX Yes but that requires Frechet derivatives for a stronger result so I thought there may be something weaker

Comment: @JackM That's true but if the first argument isn't trivial (in my case it isn't) then maybe that won't occur

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is sufficient that $F$ is a contraction in the second argument:

Suppose that $F$ is Lipschitz in the sense that
$$\|F(x,h) - F(x,g)\| \le L_1 \, \| h - g\|,\qquad
\|F(x,h) - F(y,h)\| \le L_2 \, |x - y|$$
for some constants $L_1, L_2$ and all $x,y \in [0,1]$, $f,g \in H$.

Then,
$$
\| f(x) - f(y) \| \le \| F(x,f(x)) - F(x,f(y))\| + \|F(x,f(y))-F(y,f(y))\|
\le L_1 \, \|f(x) - f(y)\| + L_2 \, |x - y|.$$
In case $L_1 < 1$ this implies
$$
\|f(x) - f(y)\| \le \frac{L_2}{1-L_1} \, |x-y|.$$

Comment: Thank you very much